# How to set rounded corner to Image in Stimulsoft Report?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, report, stimulsoft

I Want To Border-Radius : 50%; In StimulSoft But I Can not Do It.
Help Me Please Thank You...

Comment: please put some code here, or else what do you expect to get as answer beside the RTFM ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You'd better provide the corresponding code if it is convenient, so that you can better solve the problem. Or you can read this article, maybe it will help you：https://www.kessler.de/prd/stimulsoft/Stimulsoft_Reports_Manual.En.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'd like to make that image round. Adding a 100px border-radius to a 50px image won't work. Use percentage instead. For example, to make a square image look round use the following style:

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

If it doesn't work, likely another style is overwriting it, so try with the important tag:

```
border-radius: 50% !important;
```

If that also fails (could be overwritten by another !important tag somewhere in your css) try to style it inline:

```
<img src={Logo} height="50" width="50" style="border-radius: 50%" />
```